# Bounded real-valued set is compact but not closed?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded.

From Baby Rudin Theorem 3.6b:

> Every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^k$ contains a convergent subsequence.

Let $\{x_n\}$ be any sequence in $E$. Since $E$ is bounded, then $\{x_n\}$ is bounded. Using the above theorem, then there is a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ which converges to some $x \in E$.

By definition, then $E$ is *sequentially compact*. In metric spaces, sequential compactness is equivalent to compactness. Hence, $E$ is compact. It then follows that $E$ is closed by Baby Rudin's Theorem 2.34:

> Compact subsets of metric spaces are closed.

---

However, suppose $E = (0, 1)$ which is clearly bounded but not closed. The logic above seems like it'll still hold up until the end, but contradicting the conclusion that $E$ is closed.

What is the issue in the logic above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim about boundedness and convergent subsequences holds for $\mathbb{R}^n$, not necessarily any subset thereof. That is, Rudin's theorem only can tell you that there is a subsequence converging to some limit, not necessarily in $E$, but in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Taking your $E = (0,1)$ example, for instance, all subsequences of $\{1/n\}
_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converge to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, but as $0 \not \in E$, none of these subsequences converge in $E$.

What needs to be bounded, as in Rudin's claim, is the sequence, not the space in which the sequence lives. Even if the space in question is bounded, you can only guarantee subsequential convergence in $\overline{E}$ at best, not necessarily in $E$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Subtle misunderstanding of the Rudin theorem.

Answer (score 3):

The mistake in your reasoning is that nothing about the result you quoted says that when you apply it to a subspace $E$, the limit is in $E$. The subsequence converges, but why is $x \in E$? It doesn't have to be, as examples such as $1-1/n$ show.